# How to get Contract State from vaultService of MockNode in Corda M12.1?

Tags: corda

I have created the MockNetwork and MockNodes for testing the CorDapp.
Then I successfully executed the Flows with State. It help me to store states on ledger.

I'm able to fetch previously stored state using :

```
mockNode1.rpcOps.vaultAndUpdates().first
        .filterStatesOfType<SsiState>()
```

**But unable to fetch same states using vaultService of mockNode1**:

```
mockNode1.services.vaultService.track().first.states
```

or

```
mockNode1.vault.track().first.states
```

what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to rebase to Corda M13. In M12.1, the new vault query interface (`query()`, `track()`) was only partially implemented, hence why it is not behaving as expected.

Alternatively, if you wish to remain on M12.1 you can use `mockNode1.services.vaultService.states()` instead. It is worth noting that this method will be deprecated going forward in favour of the new interface which you initially tried to use and which is defined here: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault.html

Comment: I tried using **vault.states(
            setOf(SsiState::class.java),
            EnumSet.of(Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED)
        ).map { it.state.data}** but I'm still getting result zero.

Comment: Try unconsumed.